# ¿Cuál es el origen de la frase "a decir verdad"?

Tags: locuciones

El significado de la frase es claro. La entrada en el DLE es:

**[a decir verdad, o a la verdad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bbdGpd4)**

> 1. *locs. advs*. de verdad (‖ de manera cierta).

Pero es la construcción de la frase como tal la que no me parece intuitiva. Yo hubiera esperado algo como: "diciendo la verdad" o algo por el estilo. Por otra parte no es una construcción que se pueda generalizar a otras situaciones (según mi opinión), por ejemplo, no creo que nadie diga: "a decir mentira" ¿Hay alguna explicación acerca del origen de esta frase? ¿Cómo se debe interpretar el "a decir"?

Comment: Creo que es como por ejemplo "a juzgar por ...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el CORDE, parece que el origen de la expresión es "ir a decir verdad":

> *Quando los villanos realencos quisieran pleitear, vayan al mercado ante el alcalde del rey, y oidas las partes y sus querellas, el alcalde dara termino para la probança dentro del qual el dicho alcalde o sus offiçiales mandaran çitar a todos los testigos que vayan ante el a decir verdad.*
>
> Anónimo, "Fuero reducido de Navarra", a1530 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *De arte que la gracia es una como deidad y una como figura viva del mismo Cristo, que, puesta en el alma, se lanza en ella y la deifica, y, si va a decir verdad, es el alma del alma.*
>
> Fray Luis de León, "De los nombres de Cristo, libros I-III", 1583 (España).

En el mismo siglo XVI ya se pueden encontrar usos de "a decir verdad" omitiendo el verbo:

> *Aunque (a decir verdad) yo no querría,
>
>   que vuestra señoría se corriese,
>
>   por cuanto vale toda Andalucía:*
>
> *Que el no hablar con ella es interese
>
>   que se me sigue, porque no me entiendo
>
>   con término tan grave como es ése* [...]
>
> Vicente Espinel, "Diversas rimas", 1591 (España).

Por tanto, la forma correcta de interpretar ese "a decir verdad" es como una simplificación de expresiones como "si voy a decir la verdad" o "si he de decir la verdad".